# Trouble with input byte[] array to StringBuilder Java

Tags: java, string, byte

Part of my code is:

```
public String encryptBlock(String data) {
 StringBuilder encryptedString = new StringBuilder();
 encryptedString.insert(0, this.setBlock(byteData, "encrypt"));
return encryptedString.toString();
}

private String setBlock(byte[] block) {
 byte[] tmp = new byte[8];
 long xl =  bytesToLong(block);
 long xr = bytesToLong(block) >> 32;
 encipher();
 System.arraycopy(longToBytes(xl), 0, tmp, 0, 4);
 System.arraycopy(longToBytes(xr), 0, tmp, 4, 4);
return new String(tmp).toString();
}
```

I use String data like this `"12345678"`.

In `setBlock` my own methods like `bytesToLong` or `encipher` work fine, after `encipher()` method and arraycopy's i have normal `byte[]` array like this

```
( -91, 85, -54, 73, -38, -5, -58, -66)
```

then i put it into `encryptedString` in `encryptBlock`. The result in `encryptedString` is:

```
�U�I��ƾ
```

It's ok, i need result like this. So the size of my string is ok, it's 8 bytes in my `byte[] tmp`, but if i convert my `encryptedString` in to `byte[]` array i'll have this result:

```
(-17, -65, -67, 85, -17, -65, -67, 73, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -58, -66)
```

How can i fix? Or whats wrong with this strings? It's important, because i must to do my `decrypt()` function with my `encryptedString`, i also take 8 byte from string, but `encryptedString` loses dimension and has not equivalent bytes as i put it before.

Comment: A String is for characters, not bytes. Don't use a String to store bytes. Use a byte array. If you really need a printable string, then use Base64 to encode your byte array into a String. That said, the javadoc of the String constructor you're using answers your question: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-

Comment: You are converting back and forth between String and byte[], and that always involves en/decoding from UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Comment: but if i must work with **byte[] array** and result must save into **String string**, how to be?
I need't printable String but like i take at the begine  byte[] block for encipher, i must do it again for the decipher, but my String in bytes loses size

Comment: *If you really need a printable string, then use Base64 to encode your byte array into a String.*.